# Disable touch everywhere except any element

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Prompt please.
 Cocos2d:
 if I pressed the button that executes a method. so, how do I disable the touch of any one element but one of some? Ie, in the end, I can not touch the keys, except for example Buton1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and add to scene layer which have setTouchEnabled, less touch priority than every touch delegates on scene, and more touch priority than Button1.

In this case, when somebody try to tap somewhere without button1 , the layer get touch and don't send to other nodes, but when top on button the button get the touch and activate.